# Notification Feature on Android

Tags: android, webview, push-notification

I am working on an Android app in which I am fetching data from a website on our android app using Web View. I am facing an issue while working on the push notification feature, Can you please help me with this.

I need to get a notification on my app whenever there are new updates (like when a new blog is up, etc).

Comment: What issue you are facing ? Can you add logs and code so that I can answer .

Comment: This link will help you -https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: FCM provides facility to send message to all active user. You need to integrate FCM in your app.

Comment: What kind of issue are you getting can you please describe?

Comment: Actually, I tried to do it with the help of GCM but in between that procedure I had to create a new module for App Engine but the backend has already been assigned to Google Cloud Endpoint. Also, I'm new to android so I don't have the code by which I'll be able to achieve this.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I don't think that using a webview can be related to problems with push notifications...

Comment: You can use firebase which is very easy to integrate compare to GCM https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client you can get all detail here.

Comment: No, webview is not a problem, what I want is that the user is able to get the notifications regarding the website update on his/her device. And also how will I be able to do it.

Comment: Do we need to create an account on Firebase first?

Comment: If you have google account then no need to create for firebase just log in with google account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of tutorial for GCM, here are some one :

1. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html
2. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html
3. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
4. http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/
5. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

I hope above point will help you.

> ***Sending Push Notification using FCM***

**Google deprecated the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) and launched new Push notification server that is Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). FCM  is same like GCM, FCM is also a cross-platform messaging solution for mobile platforms**

Notification service, and google has something like that for us.

[image]

## How does this works??

Take a look at  the image below,

you need to register your android app in the google service, and your web interface will need an id, so every-time you want to push something to the android, your web interface instead will push it to the google server with the Id of the app, then google (no matter how) will localize your app, and even if its not running, they will get the notification,

behind the scenes there is a couple of thing that you must do, bu nothing like launching rockets from the NASA.

I will suggest to take a look to some [tutorials](http://javapapers.com/android/android-device-to-device-messaging-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-via-http/)
in order to start with the registration of your app, get the api key etc etc..

Notification messages with the [Notifications composer](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification/compose). This functionality is demonstrated in the [quickstart sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging), which you can download, run, and review.

After that check how to build [UI for notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Check this [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) for more info.